# Searchkick manual reindex on associations while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm manually calling re index on associations so that they are up-to-date as prescribed by the [docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#associations).

HOWEVER, in my testing environment, the reindex calls are throwing an error. On CI the error is an understandable port 9200 isn't running as ES is not running. Locally, the error looks more like this showing that the document doesn't exist.

I have the prescribed `Searchkick.disable_callbacks` in my test_helper

Setup:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

  searchkick

  def search_data
    { name }.merge(**client_data)
  end

  def client_data
    { market_id: client.market_id }
  end
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parents

  after_save :reindex_parents

  def reindex_parents
    parents.reindex(:client_data) # <-- ERROR raised here without `unless Rails.env.test?` guard
  end
end
```

Error:

```
TestClass#test_name:
Searchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"document_missing_exception", "reason"=>"[model][395824130]: document missing", "index_uuid"=>"5UOKtvfvR52x76Nf5njMBQ", "shard"=>"0", "index"=>"students_test"} on item with id '395824130' ....
```

I can avoid the issue by guarding the `reindex_parents` call with the an `unless Rails.env.test?` but it seems that there *should* be a better way

Am I missing something?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since callbacks are disabled, the search index won't have any data. When `reindex_parents` tries to update a document that doesn't exist, an error is thrown. Instead of `unless Rails.env.test?`, you can use `if Searchkick.callbacks?` if it feels cleaner.